# Process.Start("URL WITH UNDERSCORE"); is throwing exception

Tags: c#, url, exception, process.start

Whenever an URL is containing underscore "_" the program is throwing exception.

`Console.WriteLine` is showing an extra questionmark "?" before the url like this

```
?https://SOMEURL.com/netzdb/request_dns.php
```

and the exception text is

> The system cannot find the file specified.

Other URLs with ?, /, &, -, %, = and so on are working just fine.

```
Process.Start(WindowsFormsApplication3.Properties.Settings.Default.url6);
```

also tried this

```
Process.Start("iexplore ", WindowsFormsApplication3.Properties.Settings.Default.url6);
```

It'd be ok to open the Settings.settings stored URLs in any other way.

I will add a tick next to the buttons which are opening the URLs, if the user wants to open IE with admin rights (with pre-stored username and pw.)

Comment: *Console.WriteLine is showing an extra questionmark "?"* - Where is it doing this?  Are you sure there is not a lead `?` in the string you pass to `.Start()`?

Comment: It is probably a zero width symbol.
Go to te beginning of the string press key right and press backspace

Comment: This looks like a UTF charset prefix value is being output. What is the format of your String ? .net is Unicode by default but your string could easily be any format - the Process start probably only accepts ASCII which is why its formatting the UTF prefix as a "?" character.

Comment: Wrap the string with quotes

Comment: You mean that I've added an extra ? by accident? No. 100% not.

Comment: God... The Settings.settings haven't shown that extra space at the beginning. Nor is it visible in the actual Settings.Designer.cs file which is plain text.
I'm feeling so bad right now. Sorry for asking. :(
But why only with url's with _ in them?